Why is the ISS HD camera pointed at Flap 2?
Why is the ISS HD earth view camera pointed at Flap 2? Will that ever change? It was a much prettier view before Flap 2 entered.

Is it a reference to this?

Liam Kennedy mentioned this around 7 months ago:

That obstruction (now) in the field of view of EHDC6 (NASA's primary earth viewing camera) is the External Thermal Control System Pump Module (Spare). It was launched on SpaceX-30 (cargo resupply) and was put there by the Canadarm last week.
This will likely stay here until the existing system needs to be replaced.
So - this is what we have for the foreseeable future

and

NASA can't and won't "release it" from the view ..
... The EHDC6 camera is fixed. It does not have a pan/tilt capability that other EHDC systems have - all it can do is Zoom (which won't help with this obstruction).

https://x.com/ISSAboveYou/status/1773805118536008116



Wait, how does this actually answer the question at all?

@Starship it answers why the camera is pointed at Flap 2--the item with the Flap 2 label on its packaging was flown up there on a certain flight, the is a spare and will be staying in the field of view until it's used, and the camera isn't going to be moved.  It's not clear at all to me why you don't think it's an answer.

I suppose while "because it was put there" is technically an answer to the question, the implicit question is probably "why wasn't it put somewhere else that's not obstructing the camera?" And for that implicit question probably it's because it's the only place to store it?

@justhalf to the question "Why is the ISS HD camera pointed at Flap 2?", Because that's where they put Flap 2" is pretty much exactly to the question as-asked. If there were other location options, I'm sure there were several more important criteria used to choose among them than "would it block the Earth-pointing public relations camera?"

Yea, and that's the implicit answer :)
